# Waiting for meetlookup.com

Tags: wordpress

When my site's WordPress admin dashboard is loading, I get a suspicious message on the bottom-left of the page, saying `Waiting for meetlookup.com...`.

The message should be `Waiting for <my_domain>.<my_tld>...`

I think my site has been hacked by some malicious plugin or theme, but I don't know how to address the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It seems like the spyware has a time delay so it only activates after a certain number of weeks, in order to evade detection. So turning it off and on again will be to no avail, as it won't make those `meetlookup.com` when you turn it on again. For that reason, it's best to disable each web browser extension, one at a time.

Comment: For me it was caused by a spyware web browser extension called [Link Roamer](https://www.linkroamer.com/)

Comment: It's also caused by [Link Roamer](https://www.linkroamer.com/) and [Reverse Image Search](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/reverse-image-search/ibmfjngadieonblglgamabghhaimfldg?hl=en-GB) by Andreas

Answer (score 2):

in my experience, that's caused by browser extension, you can try with disable your extension and try reload.

Comment: In my case, it was Rapid Translator Chrome extension that was introducing these links being loaded for any site I was loading, along side bunch of other URLs. Specially when I was highlighting something and right click to do a Google search on it. I looked up in the Chrome Extension store and it had been removed -- for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer or certain solution, but I was experiencing the same behavior on one of my desktops.  Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa using Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77
I ran a security check of my extensions with nothing coming back as suspect.  I disabled one (Getcolor) and cannot replicate the "waiting for meetlookup.com" after that.  Interestingly that particular extension that I just installed to use once last week appears to no longer be listed in the Chrome web store.

Comment: I can replicate the same behaviour too after deactivating Getcolor.

Answer (score 0):

It is spyware. After uninstalling all extensions are gone. I recommend changing your passwords as they were exposed :(